# How to auto close an auto encryption mode buffer in emacs?

Tags: emacs, gnupg

I keep some stuff in a file 'XXX.gpg' which I read and edit with emacs auto encryption mode.

In some cases I forget to close the buffer for a long time which is some kind of risk.

I would like to have the buffer automatically saved and closed after some time (of inactivity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `run-with-idle-timer` to construct a function doing exactly what you want.

Comment: jogeba: May I suggest that you at least up-vote an answer which has proved helpful to you, if you're not going to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

this is what i use:

```
(defun dwim-kill-gpg-buffers ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((buffers-killed 0))
    (dolist (buffer (buffer-list))
      (with-current-buffer buffer
        (when (string-match ".*\.gpg$" (buffer-name buffer))
          (let ((current-time (second (current-time)))
                (last-displayed-time (second buffer-display-time)))
            (when (> (- current-time last-displayed-time)
                     60)
              (message "Auto killing .gpg buffer '%s'" (buffer-name buffer))
              (when (buffer-modified-p buffer)
                (save-buffer))
              (kill-buffer buffer)
              (incf buffers-killed))))))
    (unless (zerop buffers-killed)
      (message "%s .gpg buffers have been autosaved and killed" buffers-killed))))

(run-with-idle-timer 60 t 'dwim-kill-gpg-buffers)
```

it tries not to close a buffer that has recently been displayed, so as long as there's view-switching activity, killing of the buffer is delayed.

Answer (score 0):

Now I use this in my ~/.emacs:

```
(run-with-idle-timer 60 t (lambda ()
                         (let ((victim (get-buffer "XXX.gpg")))
                           (when victim (message "Killing buffer %s" (buffer-name victim)
                                                 (kill-buffer victim))))))
```